# É permitido fazer citações de uma determinada empresa, citando nomes?

Tags: suporte

Posso realizar citações e colocar o nome da empresa que fez essa citação possuindo uma fonte?

Comment: Este espaço é publico. Assim, evitando propaganda, todos somos livres de referir empresas/pessoas. Cabe a cada um bom senso, respeito. Se fôr para dizer mal é preciso pensar duas vezes. Se fôr para dizer bem, não vejo mal. Tens um caso concreto de exemplo?

Comment: Eu fiz referência a MailChimp para defender meu argumento, a citação está em minha resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102402/globals-para-armazenar-configura%C3%A7%C3%B5es/102436#102436 - Se tiver algo que não se enquadra nos padrões eu posso editar.

Comment: Não tem problema nenhum no que você disse, se encaixa no contexto da resposta. Como disse o @Sergio, haveria problema se você estivesse fazendo propaganda descarada (spam), ou ofendendo.

Comment: Só acho que poderia ter traduzido, mesmo usando o google tradutor, nem sempre fica uma tradução precisa e são poucos o que tem bom dominio sobre o inglês :)

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, irei fazer isso.

Comment: Ainda não traduzido, mas relevante ao tema da pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion